# Web Deployment Tool on Win2k8 R2

Tags: windows, iis, internet

I'm trying to install Web Deployment Tool on Win2k8 R2, but always fail with the next error:

```
MSI (s) (D4:20) [16:53:38:151]: Created Custom Action Server with PID 3780 (0xEC4).
MSI (s) (D4:FC) [16:53:38:182]: Running as a service.
**MSI (s) (D4:FC) [16:53:38:182]: Hello, I'm your 32bit Elevated Non-remapped custom action server.
Error 1720. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A script required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. Custom action InstallEtwManifest script error -2146827859, Microsoft VBScript runtime error: ActiveX component can't create object: 'oLocator.ConnectServer' Line 9, Column 13, 
MSI (s) (D4:18) [16:53:47:371]: Product: Microsoft Web Deploy 3.6 -- Error 1720. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A script required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. Custom action InstallEtwManifest script error -2146827859, Microsoft VBScript runtime error: ActiveX component can't create object: 'oLocator.ConnectServer' Line 9, Column 13,**

MSI (s) (D4:18) [16:53:47:371]: Closing MSIHANDLE (121) of type 0 for thread 2584
MSI (s) (D4:18) [16:53:47:371]: Closing MSIHANDLE (120) of type 790536 for thread 4764
Action ended 16:53:49: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.
MSI (s) (D4:9C) [16:53:49:836]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (D4:9C) [16:53:49:836]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
```

(This is not all the LOG file.)

I also try to install in another Win2k8 R2 (this one without IIS I Think) everything works without any problem.

Also, I got procmon saves of a good and bad version and trying to get some info from there.

I spend the whole day trying to install this app, search with our friend google, a lot of posts but nothing solves the problem, 8h and not even a different error.

Thanks in advance for everyone.